# fetch data from postgreSQl db to oracle Db using PlsQl

Tags: postgresql, oracle, extract

We have a PostgreSQL which is installed in openshift container DB.
I wanted to fetch data from few tables in Postgres Db(PostgreSQL) and load it to Oracle Db.

Please give me some idea on how to connect and fetch the data from Postgres.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to do some search and attempts? As is, this question appears too broad for SO

Comment: You can push the data from Postgres to Oracle using a foreign data wrapper in Postgres. Or you can use Oracle's "Heterogeneous Services" to connect from Oracle to Postgres

Comment: A process in an oracle database can query another database (oracle or other) via a 'db link'.  If that other database is non-oracle, then you add in the Oracle Transparent Gateway (a component of "Heterogeneous Services" mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name.  I've given you good clues on what to research. In addition, There is a good overview of OTG workings here:  https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/

Comment: @EdStevens: I always though Oracle's dblink (`create database link`)  only works with another Oracle server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - nope.  At the point of the db link, it doesn't even know _what_ the other database is.  Go back and look closely.  The db link ends up just providing a net address to a listener.  It doesn't know or care what the listener creates a connection to.

Comment: @EdStevens: but the dblink still requires Heterogeneous Services if you want to connect to a non-Oracle database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - true enough.  But the db link itself knows nothing about that.  The closest he would get would be that the HOST property of the link would reference a tns net service name that includes "HS=OK" in the connect data.  It's all abstracted from the link itself.